# How to perform curl command for windows

Tags: python, curl

This is the command I am using on linux in python.

```
command = subprocess.Popen["curl", "http://snmp:xxxx@xx.xx.xx.x:80/ons.cgi?led=00100000"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = command.communicate()[0]
```

How can I perform the equivalent curl command on windows using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most painless combination of tools for working on windows for me is  [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) ,[Cygwin](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin),and [Cyg-get](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get).

You should use Chocolatey because it will take care of adjusting the `PATH` environment variable for cygwin and for all other tools you might install on windows:

Please double check this command with the official [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) website, I'm posting this here for convenience:(run in administrator cmd.exe)

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

Cygwin makes many tools from the unix world available on windows. Installl it from chocolatey by typing:

```
choco install cygwin
```

Cyg-get is like `apt-get` on ubuntu systems and allows you to install packages for cygwin from the command line.

```
choco install cyg-get
```

To get `curl` type this in an elevated command prompt.:

```
cyg-get install curl
```

`curl` is most likely not the last *nix utility you would like to use and you're not going to regret having a package manager for windows.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks. Wow chocolatey is great had never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyCURL (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) and make it platform independent.

(You will probably also need to get the cURL library from here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)